# Jekyll theme error

Tags: jekyll

Tried to change the default theme. First tried the hacker theme, then the primer theme. Got the same error both times:

`jekyll 3.5.0 | Error:  Could not locate the included file 'head.html' in any of ["/home/david/Sites/dwmclaughlin.com/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site source.`

I created head.html, then ran jekyll serve. Got the same error but this time it was header.html that was missing. I kept going and created the missing files. Got to the CSS file and got this error:

`jekyll 3.5.0 | Error:  Invalid US-ASCII character "\xE2" on line 5`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install the theme and run Jekyll?

Comment: Followed these instructions: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/

Comment: `bundle install` and then `bundle exec jekyll s`.

Comment: Same error unfortunately.

Comment: Detail the steps of what you have done to change the default theme.

Comment: The gems are downloaded already so I skip that step. I updated them, though with bundle update. Changed the theme in the config.yml file to jekyll-theme-hacker. Saved. Ran bundle exec jekyll serve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are including `_head.html` you probably have a `_layouts` directory which would prevent the hacker theme to load properly, remove the `_layouts` directory (or copy that directory from the jekyll-theme-hacker folder) and then it should work.

You probably would have to fix the layout used in posts to use the `default` layout (they probably has the `post` layout now)

Comment: Yea I did add a layouts folder to change the h1 tag from posts to problems. Probably should have mentioned that. So yea maybe that's it. I'll try it.